# I am executing following procedure in oracle but get compilation error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Actually I want to get usernames from table using Stored Procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetRecord
    ( 
       p_ID   IN  integer       ,                  
      p_user OUT VARCHAR2  
    ) 
    AS 
    BEGIN  
       SELECT  
       USERNAMES   
       INTO   
        p_user  
        FROM   tblUsers
     WHERE  ID  = p_ID  ; 

     END  GetRecord;


 BEGIN
  DECLARE A VARCHAR2
 EXECUTE GetRecord(21,A);
 END
```

When I run the above procedure I got following errors

```
Error starting at line : 17 in command -
BEGIN
DECLARE A VARCHAR2
EXECUTE GetRecord(21,A);
END
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
The symbol ";" was substituted for "EXECUTE" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Actually I want to get usernames from table using Stored Procedure

Answer (score 3):

The code that you are using to execute your procedure appears to be incorrect.  It sounds like you want

```
DECLARE
  l_usernames tblUsers.usernames%type;
BEGIN
  GetRecord( 21, l_usernames );
END;
```

In general, I'd strongly object to your naming convention.  It makes no sense to use a plural `usernames` as a column name.  A procedure named `GetRecord` tells you nothing about what it does-- `GetUsername` would be much more meaningful.  Your anonymous block also appears to be declaring a local variable `a` that stores the returned username which also makes no sense from the standpoint of using meaningful identifiers.

I'd also suggest that a procedure is the wrong approach here.  If your goal is to return a single value, use a function.  Functions return things, procedures do not.  A function can potentially be used in a SQL statement, a procedure cannot be.

Comment: I want to return number of usernames using stored procedure
How can I do this Sir?

Comment: I am new to oracle I need your guidance

Comment: @user3671390 - If you're asking a new question, please ask a new question.  If you need to clarify the question you're asking, please edit your question.  What does "number of usernames" mean in this context?  Are you trying to return some sort of count (the number of usernames that match some condition)?  Are you trying to return a collection of usernames?  Are you trying to return a `sys_refcursor` that includes username?  Or something else?

Comment: Sir,Yes I am trying to return a collection of usernames?

Comment: @user3671390 - OK.  That sounds like a new question, then.  When you post the new question, tell us what specific type of collection you are trying to return.  Are you trying to return a nested table?  An associative array?  Or a varray?  If you're returning a nested table, are you trying to return a collection defined in SQL or in PL/SQL?  Posting the actual definition of the collection you're trying to return would be helpful.